# electron: BrowserWindow.on close prompt not working

Tags: electron

I have a normal electron app using React. And I wan to show a prompt before being closed.
The expected behavior is When I click on the "X" button,  the window has to stay open and show the dialog before closing it so that I can choose if I really want to quit or not.
But instead, this is what happens [image: issue with electron]
The electron window closes before showing the dialog. And the dialog closes on its own before i click on any button.
Here is the code included in the main.dev.ts

```
 mainWindow.on('close',(e) => {
  var choice = dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow,
    {
      type: 'question',
      buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
      title: 'Confirm',
      message: 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
   });
   if(choice == 1){
     e.preventDefault();
   }});
```

I've already checked if there are some helfpul questions here on stackoverflow but found none.
Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you show a confirmation prompt you need to call `e.preventDefault();` either way to keep the window open.

Then if they click "Yes", close the window separately.

However you get a problem where once the window closes after the user clicks "Yes" it'll trigger the `close` event again, causing an infinite loop. I've fixed this problem with the `hasConfirmedClose` variable below.

Here's what'll work:

```js
var hasConfirmedClose = false;
mainWindow.on('close', (e) => {
    if (!hasConfirmedClose) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default no matter what.
        var choice = dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow, {
            type:    'question',
            buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
            title:   'Confirm',
            message: 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
        });
        if (choice == 1) {
            hasConfirmedClose = true;
            mainWindow.close();
        }
    }
});
```